# GitLab CI caching key

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Say I have the following step in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
setup_vue:
 image: ....
 stage: setup
 script:
   - cd vue/
   - npm install --no-audit
 cache:
   key: node-cache
   paths: 
     - vue/node-modules/
```

I see;

```
Checking cache for node-cache-1...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
```

And after the script runs:

```
Creating cache node-cache-1...
Created cache
WARNING: vue/node-modules/: no matching files 
No URL provided, cache will be not uploaded to shared cache server. Cache will be stored only locally. 
Job succeeded
```

When I try to get the cache on the next step like so:

```
test_vue:
 image: ....
 stage: test
 cache:
   key: node-cache
 script:
   - cd docker-hotreload-vue
   - cqc src
   - npm test
```

It doesnt try to retrieve any cache, and just tries to run the script (which fails obviously). According to the [GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#how-archiving-and-extracting-works) this is the correct way to do this. (I'm using a docker runner)

Here's the output I get:

```
Fetching changes...
fatal: remote origin already exists.
Removing vue/node_modules/
HEAD is now at ....
Checking out ...

Skipping Git submodules setup
$ cd docker-hotreload-vue
$ cqc src
```

I am using tags to ensure the same runner is executing the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your key to the below:

```
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
```

This solved my problem. I had 3 stages - build, test, package. Without the key set to `${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}`, the cache only worked for test stage. After updating the key, now the package stage can also extract the cache properly.

Comment: Caches are there for speed up build processes when downloading dependencies with for excample npm or composer. You should not use the cache to hand over created files from one stage to another, but instead use artifacts. See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html