# Gitlab - cache error message about no URL

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following logic in my GitLab-ci:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy


job_make_zip:
  tags:
    - test123
  image: node:10.19
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - make
    - make source-package
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
    - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    when:
    paths:
      - test.bz2
    expire_in: 2 days
```

When the job runs, I see the following message:

```
17 Restoring cache
18 Checking cache for master...
19 No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
20 Successfully extracted cache
```

I'm just new to Gitlab... and so I can't tell if this is an error or not.  I basically don't want to have to download the same npm modules every single time this build runs.
I found a similar post here: [GitLab CI caching key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512534/gitlab-ci-caching-key)
But I'm already using the correct gitlab CI variable.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my GitLab-CI setup at home I am getting this warning (in my case I am not considering it to be an error) in all of my build jobs. According to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/201861 and https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/16097 there seem to be cases where this is a message to be taken seriously.

This is especially true if you are uploading (and later on downloading / extracting) the cache to a particular URL, which is used by several runners to get and sync the cache. In a general case though - meaning that if the cache is stored on a single GitLab-Runner rather than on a shared source, which is supposed to be used by several GitLab-Runners, I don't think this message has any real meaning. On my GitLab-Runners, which usually are project- or group-specific, this never was a problem and I always had the cache properly extracted in a local manner.